# How to call a property using a random method?

Tags: javascript, object, quote

I am trying to build a quote generator using an object instead of an array.

I am able to get results but instead of getting the quote, I am getting the name of the quote.

I tried using the bind method, however, there was no result.

Any help, please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quote Generatr</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="background">
            <h1>2018 Reading Notes</h1>
            <p>Motivational Quotes</p>
        </div>
        <p id="quotes"></p>
        <button class='btn btn-danger mt-4' style="border-radius: 0px; font-size: 2rem;">Show me another Quote</button>
        <p class="mt-5">Made with ❤️️ by Anthony</p>
    </div>


    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

var paragraph = document.querySelector('#quotes');
var butonGenerator = document.querySelector('.btn');

var quotes = {
    quote1: {
        author: 'Carol Burnett',
        quote: 'Only I can change my life. No one can do it for me.'
    },
    quote2: {
        author: 'Norman Vaughan',
        quote: 'Dream Big and Date to Fail.'
    },
    quote3:{
        author:'Jean-Claude Van damme',
        quote:'I now truly belive it is impossible for me to make a bad movie.'
    }

}


butonGenerator.addEventListener('click', quoteGenerator);

function quoteGenerator(){
    var count = 0;
    for(var value in quotes){
        if(Math.random() < 1/count++)
        paragraph.innerHTML = value;
       console.log(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an array of objects instead of an object of objects.

Comment: Can you explain any further, please?

Comment: What's the point of using `quote1`, `quote2` keys? Looks like it's just more work to type with no benefit…!?

Comment: Thank for your opinion @deceze. I am experimenting and getting to know better how javascript works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow missed the part where you didn't want to use an array. But that is definitely the way to go. See below.

You should have an array of quotes. See below snippet. Put the javascript in `<script></script>` tags below the `</body>` tag

```js
var paragraph = document.querySelector('#quotes');
var butonGenerator = document.querySelector('.btn');

var quotes = [
    {
        author: 'Carol Burnett',
        quote: 'Only I can change my life. No one can do it for me.'
    },
    {
        author: 'Norman Vaughan',
        quote: 'Dream Big and Date to Fail.'
    },
    {
        author:'Jean-Claude Van damme',
        quote:'I now truly belive it is impossible for me to make a bad movie.'
    }

]


butonGenerator.addEventListener('click', quoteGenerator);

function quoteGenerator(){
    var item = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];
 console.log(item.author);
 console.log(item.quote);
 paragraph.innerHTML = 'Author:<br />' + item.author + '<br /><br />Quote:<br />' + item.quote;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quote Generatr</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="background">
            <h1>2018 Reading Notes</h1>
            <p>Motivational Quotes</p>
        </div>
        <p id="quotes"></p>
        <button class='btn btn-danger mt-4' style="border-radius: 0px; font-size: 2rem;">Show me another Quote</button>
        <p class="mt-5">Made with ❤️️ by Anthony</p>
    </div>


    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help as it almost works, However the result that I am generating is of undefined, undefined once the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why are you trying to use an object in this case but if that's a must, you might find Object.keys(quotes) useful as it returns the actual keys (so in your case the 'quote1', 'quote2', etc.) of your object as an array.
Then you could create a random number, retrieve the given index from the array created here and use that string to access the object properties.

```
var array = Object.keys(quotes); // convert the object to an array of it's keys
var key = array[randomIndex]; // get a random key
var quoteObject = quotes[key]; // use it to access the property of the object.
```

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Anyways you should always use an array in this case if you are able to.

Comment: Thanks appreciate it.